# How to wite a constructor for child that need to run when parent is working?

Tags: php, class, constructor

I have a parent class doing logging job on all activities.
Now I want to use a child class to add additional data to some of the activities. That means I need parent's vars about the activities, and I need to run the child when the parent is called.

This is the parent's constructor:

```
function CD_Log( $id = false ) {
    $this->__construct( $id );
}

function __construct( $id = false ) {

    if ( !empty( $id ) ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->populate();
    }
}
```

This is how I think the child constructor would be:

```
function __construct( $args = array() ) {

    parent::__construct($child_id);

    $defaults = array(
    'child_id'    => 0, //the child has its own id
    'child_data'  => 0,  //extra data
    'parent_data' => $this->data // inheritage from parent
    );
}
```

In the functions that call the child, I will provide the default data array. The child will be called at the same place as parent being called. Does this code work?

Comment: i think you're doing the whole inheritance thing the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the question several times and find it incredibly confusing. I would really like to help you out but think it would be easier if you clarified more on exactly what you want and what the system is supposed to do.

Why do you have to run the parent class when running the child class? Could you try and delegate the information into the child class? Also, why are you calling the constructor through another method when it will be initialized before the `CD_Log` method anyway?

Comment: I want some of the parent's data on the same object which is a big job if re-code to get it. If I use $new = New CD_Log($id),then, I need to know what's the id to match the child's current object.

Comment: Why would you want to use a parent class at all when you could just _use_ the child class which would inherit all of the parent's properties and methods anyway?

Comment: if don't use parent, where the child inherit things from?

Comment: You don't need to instantiate the parent class in order to use it. You can include/require it **before** you instantiate the child class and it will thus inherit properly. But this also means that all the values you used to lend to the parent class you will now instead give to the child class which will basically be the same as the child holds all the parent's methods and properties. Classes are blueprints, not objects, hence why you don't need to 'build' the parent class in order to use it, as long you got the recipe.

Comment: I don't think I can include parent class file. It's a big program,the calss is merely a structure, most of data are set by other functions which are also big peices.

Comment: Ouch, then that might be a big problem. This is why refactoring can be such a pain. Which information exactly is it you need to send to the child class and __why__ do you need to send it to the child class at all? Running two instances of 'the same "class"' sounds like overcomplicating things.

Comment: yes, it's sort of duplicate. The parent is a class to log everything happening on the website. A few items that happening are going to be paid, I want to use the child to record them. So, the parent and the child are doing the same thing, but the child will add the payment for some of the items. In the child, I still need to keep record of the item's property which is the same record as parent's.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4454/discussion-between-seralize-and-jenny)